Unable to generate the combination x and combination y using python
Unable to generate desired combination 2 and combination 5
Current OutPut
Combination 1: Rutgers (93), Baylor (93), Orlando (96), Dublin (96), Spokane (96)
Combination 2: Rutgers (89), Baylor (90), Orlando (90), Dublin (85), Spokane (85)

Expected Output Something like this.
COMBINATION 2: Trenton (89), Alabama (93), Orlando (96), Atlanta (96), Chicago (90)
COMBINATION 3: Rutgers (89), Baylor (93), Miami (96), Atlanta (85), SFO (90)
COMBINATION 4: Alabama (89), Trenton (93), Dublin (96), Chicago (96), Seattle (90)
COMBINATION 5: Baylor (89), Rutgers (93), SFO (96), Seattle (96),  Trenton (90)
COMBINATION 6: Orlando (89), Atlanta (93), Spokane (96), Trenton (96), Alabama (85)

.
.
.
.

These are conditions  we added for the code to reach my expectations.
-The team should have different points as per point_constraints,
Example
COMBINATION 2: Trenton (89), Alabama (93), Orlando (96), Atlanta (96), Chicago (90)
COMBINATION 3: Rutgers (89), Baylor (93), Miami (96), Atlanta (85), SFO (90)

-Pick only 1 Team from each set
-5 team combination
Criteria -
The criteria for the combinations follows these rules:

Team Selection from Different Sets:

You pick one team from each set (A, B, C, D, E, J) for each combination. Each team in a combination must be from a different set, and no team should be repeated in the same combination.

Point Constraints:

You apply the point constraints for each score when forming combinations. The constraints indicate how many times a score can be used in the set of combinations.
The constraints are:

"89": (0, 1) — This score can appear 0 or 1 time in a combination.
"93": (0, 1) — This score can appear 0 or 1 time in a combination.
"96": (0, 2) — This score can appear 0, 1, or 2 times in a combination.
"85": (0, 1) — This score can appear 0 or 1 time in a combination.
"90": (0, 1) — This score can appear 0 or 1 time in a combination.


Combination Size:

Each combination should consist of 5 teams, one from each set, with their associated points.

Elimination of Used Points:

Once a combination is made, the points used in that combination are eliminated from further combinations. This ensures that no points are reused from the same teams in subsequent combinations.

Repeat the Process:

After creating a valid combination, the process is repeated with the remaining teams and their available points, forming another valid combination based on the same constraints.
CODE

 from itertools import combinations, product
import random

# Define the teams and scores for each set
sets = {
    "set_A": {
        "Trenton": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"],
        "Rutgers": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"],
    },
    "set_B": {
        "Alabama": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"],
        "Baylor": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"],
    },
    "set_C": {
        "Orlando": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"],
        "Miami": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"],
    },
    "set_D": {
        "Atlanta": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"],
        "Dublin": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"],
    },
    "set_E": {
        "Chicago": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"],
        "SFO": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"],
    },
    "set_J": {
        "Seattle": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"],
        "Spokane": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"],
    }
}

# Define the score constraints (min, max) allowed for each score
score_constraints = {
    "89": (0, 1),
    "93": (0, 1),
    "96": (0, 2),
    "85": (0, 1),
    "90": (0, 1),
}

# Function to count score occurrences in a combination
def count_score_occurrences(selected_scores, score_constraints):
    score_counts = {score: 0 for score in score_constraints}
    for score in selected_scores:
        if score in score_counts:
            score_counts[score] += 1
    return score_counts

# Function to validate if a combination meets the score constraints
def is_valid_combination(score_counts, score_constraints):
    return all(min_count <= score_counts[score] <= max_count for score, (min_count, max_count) in score_constraints.items())

# Flatten the sets to prepare for team selection
all_teams = []
for set_name, teams in sets.items():
    for team_name, scores in teams.items():
        all_teams.append((set_name, team_name, scores))

# Generate combinations of 5 different teams from different sets
valid_combinations = []
used_scores = set()  # To track scores already used

# Limit one team from each set
team_combinations = list(combinations(all_teams, 5))

# Shuffle the combinations for randomness
random.shuffle(team_combinations)

for team_combination in team_combinations:
    # Ensure all teams in this combination come from different sets
    set_names = {team[0] for team in team_combination}
    if len(set_names) < 5:
        continue  # Skip if two teams come from the same set
    
    # Extract the score lists for each team in the combination
    score_lists = [team[2] for team in team_combination]
    
    # Generate all possible score combinations for this team combination
    for score_combination in product(*score_lists):
        # Check for duplicate scores in the combination
        if any(score in used_scores for score in score_combination):
            continue  # Skip if any score has already been used
        
        # Count occurrences of each score
        score_counts = count_score_occurrences(score_combination, score_constraints)
        
        # Validate the score combination
        if is_valid_combination(score_counts, score_constraints):
            # Add this combination's scores to the used scores set
            used_scores.update(score_combination)
            
            # Combine team names with their valid scores
            team_combination_with_scores = [
                f"{team[1]} ({score})" for team, score in zip(team_combination, score_combination)
            ]
            valid_combinations.append(team_combination_with_scores)
            
        # Limit the number of valid combinations to 900
        if len(valid_combinations) >= 900:
            break

# Print the number of valid combinations found
print(f"Number of valid combinations: {len(valid_combinations)}")

# Write the valid combinations to a text file
with open("swat9.txt", "w") as file:
    for idx, combination in enumerate(valid_combinations, 1):
        file.write(f"Combination {idx}: {', '.join(combination)}\n")

print("Valid combinations written to 'oct9.txt' file.")



Combination 1: Rutgers (93), Baylor (93), Orlando (96), Dublin (96), Spokane (96)


Expected Output Something like this.

COMBINATION 2: Trenton (89), Alabama (93), Orlando (96), Atlanta (96), Chicago (90)
COMBINATION 3: Rutgers (89), Baylor (93), Miami (96), Atlanta (85), SFO (90)
COMBINATION 4: Alabama (89), Trenton (93), Dublin (96), Chicago (96), Seattle (90)
COMBINATION 5: Baylor (89), Rutgers (93), SFO (96), Seattle (96),  Trenton (90)
COMBINATION 6: Orlando (89), Atlanta (93), Spokane (96), Trenton (96), Alabama (85)

.
.
.
.



Process
sets = {
    "set_A": {
        "Trenton": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"],
        "Rutgers": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"],
    },
    "set_B": {
        "Alabama": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"],
        "Baylor": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"],
    },
    "set_C": {
        "Orlando": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"],
        "Miami": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"],
    },
    "set_D": {
        "Atlanta": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"],
        "Dublin": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"],
    },
    "set_E": {
        "Chicago": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"],
        "SFO": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"],
    },
    "set_J": {
        "Seattle": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"],
        "Spokane": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"],
    }
}


SET A--Trenton--93,--Trenton--96,--Trenton--89,--Trenton--90,--Trenton--85,
SET A--Rutgers--93,--Rutgers--96,--Rutgers--89,--Rutgers--90,--Rutgers--85,
SET B--Alabama--93,--Alabama--96,--Alabama--89,--Alabama--90,--Alabama--85,
SET B--Baylor--93,--Baylor--96,--Baylor--89,--Baylor--90,--Baylor--85,
SET C--Orlando--93,--Orlando--96,--Orlando--89,--Orlando--90,--Orlando--85,
SET C--Miami--93,--Miami--96,--Miami--89,--Miami--90,--Miami--85,
SET D--Atlanta--93,--Atlanta--96,--Atlanta--89,--Atlanta--90,--Atlanta--85,
SET D--Dublin--93,--Dublin--96,--Dublin--89,--Dublin--90,--Dublin--85,
SET E--Chicago--93,--Chicago--96,--Chicago--89,--Chicago--90,--Chicago--85,
SET E--SFO--93,--SFO--96,--SFO--89,--SFO--90,--SFO--85,
SET J--Seattle--93,--Seattle--96,--Seattle--89,--Seattle--90,--Seattle--85,
SET J--Spokane--93,--Spokane--96,--Spokane--89,--Spokane--90,--Spokane--85,



As per those conditions Pick 1 from each set accouding to the constraints 

point_constraints = {
    "89": (0, 1),
    "93": (0, 1),
    "96": (0, 2),
    "85": (0, 1),
    "90": (0, 1),
}

Create Team of 5 combinations 
COMBINATION 1- Trenton: 89,--Alabama--93,   --Orlando--96, --Atlanta--96, --Chicago--90


SET A--Trenton--93,--Trenton--96,               --Trenton--90,--Trenton--85,
SET A--Rutgers--93,--Rutgers--96,--Rutgers--89,--Rutgers--90,--Rutgers--85,
SET B               --Alabama--96,--Alabama--89,--Alabama--90,--Alabama--85,
SET B--Baylor--93,--Baylor--96,--Baylor--89,--Baylor--90,--Baylor--85,
SET C--Orlando--93,             --Orlando--89,--Orlando--90,--Orlando--85,
SET C--Miami--93,--Miami--96,--Miami--89,--Miami--90,--Miami--85,
SET D--Atlanta--93,             --Atlanta--89,--Atlanta--90,--Atlanta--85,
SET D--Dublin--93,--Dublin--96,--Dublin--89,--Dublin--90,--Dublin--85,
SET E--Chicago--93,--Chicago--96,--Chicago--89,             --Chicago--85,
SET E--SFO--93,--SFO--96,--SFO--89,--SFO--90,--SFO--85,
SET J--Seattle--93,--Seattle--96,--Seattle--89,--Seattle--90,--Seattle--85,
SET J--Spokane--93,--Spokane--96,--Spokane--89,--Spokane--90,--Spokane--85,


Remove those used Teams with POINTS
From here again as per constraints point_constraints = {
"89": (0, 1),
"93": (0, 1),
"96": (0, 2),
"85": (0, 1),
"90": (0, 1),
}


select 5 Team combinations

COMBINATION 2- Rutgers:  89,--Baylor--93, --Miami--96,--Atlanta--85,--SFO--90,

Remaining Places and their associated points
SET A--Trenton--93,--Trenton--96,               --Trenton--90,--Trenton--85,
SET A--Rutgers--93,--Rutgers--96,               --Rutgers--90,--Rutgers--85,
SET B               --Alabama--96,--Alabama--89,--Alabama--90,--Alabama--85,
SET B               --Baylor--96,--Baylor--89,--Baylor--90,--Baylor--85,
SET C--Orlando--93,             --Orlando--89,--Orlando--90,--Orlando--85,
SET C--Miami--93,               --Miami--89,--Miami--90,--Miami--85,
SET D--Atlanta--93,             --Atlanta--89,--Atlanta--90,
SET D--Dublin--93,--Dublin--96,--Dublin--89,--Dublin--90,--Dublin--85,
SET E--Chicago--93,--Chicago--96,--Chicago--89,             --Chicago--85,
SET E--SFO--93,--SFO--96,--SFO--89,             --SFO--85,
SET J--Seattle--93,--Seattle--96,--Seattle--89,--Seattle--90,--Seattle--85,
SET J--Spokane--93,--Spokane--96,--Spokane--89,--Spokane--90,--Spokane--85,
From here again as per constraints point_constraints = {
"89": (0, 1),
"93": (0, 1),
"96": (0, 2),
"85": (0, 1),
"90": (0, 1),
}


select 5 Team combinations

COMBINATION 3--Alabama--89, Trenton:--93,--Dublin--96, Chicago:  96,--Seattle--90

Remaining Places and their associated points
SET A               --Trenton--96,              --Trenton--90,--Trenton--85,
SET A--Rutgers--93,--Rutgers--96,               --Rutgers--90,--Rutgers--85,
SET B               --Alabama--96,              --Alabama--90,--Alabama--85,
SET B               --Baylor--96,--Baylor--89,--Baylor--90,--Baylor--85,
SET C--Orlando--93,             --Orlando--89,--Orlando--90,--Orlando--85,
SET C--Miami--93,               --Miami--89,--Miami--90,--Miami--85,
SET D--Atlanta--93,             --Atlanta--89,--Atlanta--90,
SET D--Dublin--93,              --Dublin--89,--Dublin--90,--Dublin--85,
SET E--Chicago--93,             --Chicago--89,              --Chicago--85,
SET E--SFO--93,--SFO--96,--SFO--89,             --SFO--85,
SET J--Seattle--93,--Seattle--96,--Seattle--89,             --Seattle--85,
SET J--Spokane--93,--Spokane--96,--Spokane--89,--Spokane--90,--Spokane--85,
From here again as per constraints point_constraints = {
"89": (0, 1),
"93": (0, 1),
"96": (0, 2),
"85": (0, 1),
"90": (0, 1),
}


select 5 Team combinations

COMBINATION 4-- --Baylor--89,--Rutgers--93,--SFO--96,--Seattle--96--Trenton--90,

Remaining Places and their associated points
SET A               --Trenton--96,              --Trenton--85,
SET A--Rutgers--96,             --Rutgers--90,--Rutgers--85,
SET B               --Alabama--96,              --Alabama--90,--Alabama--85,
SET B               --Baylor--96,               --Baylor--90,--Baylor--85,
SET C--Orlando--93,             --Orlando--89,--Orlando--90,--Orlando--85,
SET C--Miami--93,               --Miami--89,--Miami--90,--Miami--85,
SET D--Atlanta--93,             --Atlanta--89,--Atlanta--90,
SET D--Dublin--93,              --Dublin--89,--Dublin--90,--Dublin--85,
SET E--Chicago--93,             --Chicago--89,              --Chicago--85,
SET E--SFO--93--SFO--89,                --SFO--85,
SET J--Seattle--93,--Seattle--89,               --Seattle--85,
SET J--Spokane--93,--Spokane--96,--Spokane--89,--Spokane--90,--Spokane--85,


--
From here again as per constraints point_constraints = {
    "89": (0, 1),
    "93": (0, 1),
    "96": (0, 2),
    "85": (0, 1),
    "90": (0, 1),
}

select 5 Team combinations

COMBINATION 5    --Orlando--89,  Atlanta--93,    --Spokane--96,  --Trenton--96,      --Alabama--85,

Remaining Places and their associated points
SET A                                   --Trenton--85,
SET A--Rutgers--96,             --Rutgers--90,--Rutgers--85,
SET B               --Alabama--96,              --Alabama--90,
SET B               --Baylor--96,               --Baylor--90,--Baylor--85,
SET C--Orlando--93,             --Orlando--90,--Orlando--85,
SET C--Miami--93,               --Miami--89,--Miami--90,--Miami--85,
SET D--             --Atlanta--89,--Atlanta--90,
SET D--Dublin--93,              --Dublin--89,--Dublin--90,--Dublin--85,
SET E--Chicago--93,             --Chicago--89,              --Chicago--85,
SET E--SFO--93--SFO--89,                --SFO--85,
SET J--Seattle--93,--Seattle--89,               --Seattle--85,
SET J--Spokane--93,             --Spokane--89,--Spokane--90,--Spokane--85,


And so on

COMBINATION 1- Trenton:  89,--Alabama--93,   --Orlando--96, --Atlanta--96, --Chicago--90
COMBINATION 2- Rutgers:  89,--Baylor--93, --Miami--96,--Atlanta--85,--SFO--90,
COMBINATION 3--Alabama--89, Trenton:--93,--Dublin--96, Chicago:  96,--Seattle--90
COMBINATION 4-- --Baylor--89,--Rutgers--93,--SFO--96,--Seattle--96--Trenton--90,
COMBINATION 5    --Orlando--89,  Atlanta--93,--Spokane--96,--Trenton--96,--Alabama--85,


Please explain better the criteria for the combinations

Thanks I have added.

import random

# Define teams and scores for each set
teams = {
    "set_A": {"Trenton": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"], 
              "Rutgers": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"]},
    "set_B": {"Alabama": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"], 
              "Baylor": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"]},
    "set_C": {"Orlando": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"], 
              "Miami": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"]},
    "set_D": {"Atlanta": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"], 
              "Dublin": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"]},
    "set_E": {"Chicago": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"], 
              "SFO": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"]},
    "set_J": {"Seattle": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"], 
              "Spokane": ["93", "96", "89", "90", "85"]},
}

# Define score constraints (min, max allowed for each score)
score_constraints = {
    "89": [0, 1], 
    "93": [0, 1], 
    "96": [0, 2], 
    "85": [0, 1], 
    "90": [0, 1],
}

# Initialize remaining points for each team
remaining_points = {}
for set_name, teams_in_set in teams.items():
    for team_name, points in teams_in_set.items():
        remaining_points[(set_name, team_name)] = points[:]

# Function to generate combinations
def generate_combinations(num_combinations):
    combinations = []
    for _ in range(num_combinations):
        combination = []
        used_points = {}
        for set_name in teams:
            team_name = random.choice(list(remaining_points.keys()))
            while team_name[0] != set_name or not remaining_points[team_name]:
                team_name = random.choice(list(remaining_points.keys()))
            score = random.choice(remaining_points[team_name])
            while score in used_points and used_points[score] >= score_constraints[score][1]:
                score = random.choice(remaining_points[team_name])
            combination.append((team_name[1], score))
            used_points[score] = used_points.get(score, 0) + 1
            remaining_points[team_name].remove(score)
            if not remaining_points[team_name]:
                del remaining_points[team_name]
        combinations.append(combination)
    return combinations

# Generate combinations
num_combinations = 100
combinations = generate_combinations(num_combinations)

# Save combinations to a text file
with open("answer.txt", "w") as file:
    for i, combination in enumerate(combinations, 1):
        file.write(f"COMBINATION {i}: {', '.join([f'{team} ({score})' for team, score in combination])}\n")

print("Combinations have been saved to answer.txt")


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

This would be a better answer if you explained how this code is different from the original code.
